# Как устранить ошибку при компиляции .aab файла (android.enableR8)

Tags: unity3d, unity3d-android

Сделал игру, с базовыми настройками компиляции, не меняя их. При попытке загрузки aab файла в GooglePlay - мне написало что нужна архитектура ARM64, IL2CPP и Target API level не ниже 30 уровня. Поставил галку на ARM64, включил IL2CPP и установил Target API level на 30. После этого, попытался скомпилировать проект и на этапе Building Gradle project выдаёт следующую ошибку:
[image: ошибка]

Гуглил ошибку на разных форумах. Что я пытался сделать:

1. В файле gradleTemplate.properties менял `android.enableR8=**MINIFY_WITH_R_EIGHT**` на `android.enableR8=false` и даже полностью удалял эту строку.
2. Включал плагин Xr-pluginManagement>ARCore и ставил чекбокс `Ignore Gradle Version`
3. В файле BaseProjectTemplate.gradle менял `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.0'` на `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.0'`
4. `Minimum API Level` ставил на 24(включенный Xr-pluginManagement требует значение, не ниже 24)
5. Скачивал разные версии Gradle (3.4.0; 3.6.0; 5.6.1; 7.3.1) и так-же изменял их в `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle: 0.0.0'`

Использую Unity 2021.1.0f1 и редактор Visual Studio 2017.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Помогло изменение версии Unity с 2021.1.0f1 на  2020.3.24f1 (LTS), рекомендованное Unity Hub. Ошибка исчезла.